# Trouble with :hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble when it comes to hover effect on my links, it's something I've never run into before. I've posted the snippets below, but I'm stumped....

```css
.headerNav .headContainer>div>a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #E6BA6A;
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: .25s;
}

.headerNav .headContainer>div>a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.035);
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="header">

  <!-- Logo Shine Effect-->
  <div id="rainbowEffect">
    <div class="rainbowPreload orange"></div>
    <div class="rainbowPreload lime"></div>
    <div class="rainbowPreload cyan"></div>
    <div class="rainbowPreload red"></div>
    <div class="rainbowPreload purple"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="headerNav">
    <div class="headContainer headNavItems">
      <div class="navItemsLeft">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navItemsRight">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerSubNav">

  </div>
</header>
```

It seems that when I use dev tools to inspect it, and element is "getting in the way", which is the rainbowEffect. If I manually activate the hover state using the dev tools, it's fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for following the guidelines of posting a useful basic example. However, the question I have is: What is the problem that you are experiencing? When I hover over the links, I get a background per the CSS.

Comment: The hover state isn't activating for me. I should have maybe posted the full CSS

Comment: The problem probably lies in rainbowEffect is absolute positioned above the header, which means you are only every hovering over rainbowEffect.

Comment: You where right, I just have no idea how to fix without breaking everything else...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an id to each of the links and target their hover state that way. This will allow for both the dropshadow and the darkening of the link on hover. Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/5bye8x3j/

```
#hov:hover {
  color: #fcb023;
}
```

```
<div class="headContainer headNavItems">
      <div class="navItemsLeft">
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navItemsRight">
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
        <a id="hov" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that to achieve hover effect on anchor tag.

```
headerNav a:hover {
  color: #fcb023;
}
```